# Creating Anaconda virtual environment gives an error

Tags: anaconda, virtual-environment

I hope you can help me please.

I have been trying to create a virtual environment using conda but i am getting the error as below. Could someone help me interpret this please? What am i doing incorrectly here? I am guessing that it has to do with our proxy server at work but i have reconfigured the Condarc file to SSL is False.

Could it be due to my paths?

any help would be greatly appreciated.

kind regards

James

```
(base) C:\Users\jamesconnolly>conda create -name venv
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\jamesconnolly\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1079, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\jamesconnolly\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 84, in _main
        exit_code = do_call(args, p)
      File "C:\Users\jamesconnolly\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 82, in do_call
        return getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
      File "C:\Users\jamesconnolly\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_create.py", line 37, in execute
        install(args, parser, 'create')
      File "C:\Users\jamesconnolly\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\install.py", line 265, in install
        should_retry_solve=(_should_retry_unfrozen or repodata_fn != repodata_fns[-1]),
      File "C:\Users\jamesconnolly\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 117, in solve_for_transaction
        should_retry_solve)
      File "C:\Users\jamesconnolly\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 158, in solve_for_diff
        force_remove, should_retry_solve)
      File "C:\Users\jamesconnolly\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 262, in solve_final_state
        ssc = self._collect_all_metadata(ssc)
      File "C:\Users\jamesconnolly\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\io.py", line 88, in decorated
        return f(*args, **kwds)
      File "C:\Users\jamesconnolly\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 415, in _collect_all_metadata
        index, r = self._prepare(prepared_specs)
      File "C:\Users\jamesconnolly\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 1011, in _prepare
        self.subdirs, prepared_specs, self._repodata_fn)
      File "C:\Users\jamesconnolly\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\index.py", line 228, in get_reduced_index
        repodata_fn=repodata_fn)
      File "C:\Users\jamesconnolly\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py", line 105, in query_all
        result = tuple(concat(executor.map(subdir_query, channel_urls)))
      File "C:\Users\jamesconnolly\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 598, in result_iterator
        yield fs.pop().result()
      File "C:\Users\jamesconnolly\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 435, in result
        return self.__get_result()
      File "C:\Users\jamesconnolly\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
        raise self._exception
      File "C:\Users\jamesconnolly\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 57, in run
        result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\jamesconnolly\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py", line 98, in <lambda>
        package_ref_or_match_spec))
      File "C:\Users\jamesconnolly\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py", line 110, in query
        self.load()
      File "C:\Users\jamesconnolly\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py", line 174, in load
        _internal_state = self._load()
      File "C:\Users\jamesconnolly\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py", line 248, in _load
        repodata_fn=self.repodata_fn)
      File "C:\Users\jamesconnolly\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py", line 485, in fetch_repodata_remote_request
        timeout=timeout)
      File "C:\Users\jamesconnolly\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 546, in get
        return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\jamesconnolly\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
        resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\jamesconnolly\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send
        r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\jamesconnolly\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 412, in send
        conn = self.get_connection(request.url, proxies)
      File "C:\Users\jamesconnolly\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 309, in get_connection
        proxy_manager = self.proxy_manager_for(proxy)
      File "C:\Users\jamesconnolly\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 199, in proxy_manager_for
        **proxy_kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\jamesconnolly\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 470, in proxy_from_url
        return ProxyManager(proxy_url=url, **kw)
      File "C:\Users\jamesconnolly\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 420, in __init__
        raise ProxySchemeUnknown(proxy.scheme)
    urllib3.exceptions.ProxySchemeUnknown: Not supported proxy scheme None

`$ C:\Users\jamesconnolly\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py create -name venv`

  environment variables:
                 CIO_TEST=<not set>
        CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=base
                CONDA_EXE=C:\Users\jamesconnolly\Anaconda3\condabin\..\Scripts\conda.exe
               CONDA_EXES="C:\Users\jamesconnolly\Anaconda3\condabin\..\Scripts\conda.exe"
             CONDA_PREFIX=C:\Users\jamesconnolly\Anaconda3
    CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER=(base)
         CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=C:\Users\jamesconnolly\Anaconda3\python.exe
               CONDA_ROOT=C:\Users\jamesconnolly\Anaconda3
              CONDA_SHLVL=1
                 HOMEPATH=\Users\jamesconnolly
                     PATH=C:\Users\jamesconnolly\Anaconda3;C:\Users\jamesconnolly\Anaconda3\Libr
                          ary\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Users\jamesconnolly\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\
                          Users\jamesconnolly\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Users\jamesconnolly\Anaco
                          nda3\Scripts;C:\Users\jamesconnolly\Anaconda3\bin;C:\Users\jamesconnol
                          ly\Anaconda3;C:\Users\jamesconnolly\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:
                          \Users\jamesconnolly\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\jamesconnolly\
                          Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Users\jamesconnolly\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\User
                          s\jamesconnolly\Anaconda3\bin;C:\Users\jamesconnolly\Anaconda3\condabi
                          n;C:\Program Files\Python37\Scripts;C:\Program
                          Files\Python37;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin;C:\Program Files
                          (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows
                          ;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C
                          :\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
                          Server\150\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform
                          Installer;C:\Program Files\dotnet;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
                          Server\130\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service
                          Fabric\bin\Fabric\Fabric.Code;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service
                          Fabric\Tools\ServiceFabricLocalClusterManager;C:\Program
                          Files\PuTTY;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program
                          Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Python37;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS
                          Code\bin;C:\Users\jamesconnolly\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;.
             PSMODULEPATH=C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\Windows
                          PowerShell\v1.0\Modules
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
            SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>
         STTASKFOLDERPATH=\LANDESK\Protect\Deployments

     active environment : base
    active env location : C:\Users\jamesconnolly\Anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : C:\Users\jamesconnolly\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\jamesconnolly\.condarc
          conda version : 4.8.2
    conda-build version : 3.18.11
         python version : 3.7.6.final.0
       virtual packages :
       base environment : C:\Users\jamesconnolly\Anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\Users\jamesconnolly\Anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\jamesconnolly\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\jamesconnolly\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Users\jamesconnolly\Anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\jamesconnolly\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\jamesconnolly\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.8.2 requests/2.22.0 CPython/3.7.6 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.18362
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False


An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.

If submitted, this report will be used by core maintainers to improve
future releases of conda.
Would you like conda to send this report to the core maintainers?
```

Comment: You need two dashes: `conda create --name venv`. But it also looks like your proxy might be configured incorrectly, can you check that other sites work?

Comment: Dear darthbirth,

Thanks so much for the replay. 

Yes it feels like changing .condarc config has done nothing in circumventing firewall. 

This may all be due to my paths I have inherited from previous version of Anaconda being installed and then uninstalled. If I have conflict over the paths would this Prevent the condarc config issue please?

Any idea on how to troubleshoot that?

Comment: Possibly. You can delete the conda rc file, and remove any paths that were previously added to your system environment variables.

Comment: Dear DarthBirth - I will try this but please can you advise which paths I MUST have?

Comment: If you're using the Anaconda Prompt, you need no paths in your environment variables.